# How to round a pandas series of values with a series of precision?

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I am trying to round a DataFrame with 1 column of values and 1 column of precision.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1.111, 2.222, 3.333, 4.444], 'precision': [1,2,2,1]})
>>> df
   precision  value
0          1  1.111
1          2  2.222
2          2  3.333
3          1  4.444
```

To create a `rounded` column like this:

```
>>> df
   precision  value  rounded
0          1  1.111     1.1
1          2  2.222     2.22
2          2  3.333     3.33
3          1  4.444     4.4
```

I've tried the intuitive solutions:

```
>>> df['rounded'] = round(df['value'], df['precision'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Drew/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 93, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

and

```
>>> df['rounded'] = df['value'].round(df['precision'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Drew/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1999, in round
    result = com.values_from_object(self).round(decimals)
  File "/Users/Drew/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 93, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'int'>
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension to pass variables into `np.round`

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1.111, 2.222, 3.333, 4.444], 'precision': [1,2,3,1]})
print(df)

 value  precision
0  1.111          1
1  2.222          2
2  3.333          3
3  4.444          1

df['rounded'] = [np.around(x,y) for x,y in zip(df['value'],df['precision'])]
print(df)


    value  precision  rounded
0  1.111          1    1.100
1  2.222          2    2.220
2  3.333          3    3.333
3  4.444          1    4.400
```

Comment: This does not preserve the desired level of precision.

Comment: Why are you targeting my post and the one by @bigbounty does the same. Why are you only tagging mine?

Comment: This profiled faster than `apply lambda` by about a second for large datasets. `str(np.around(x,y))` solves preserving the precision. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [45]: df.apply(lambda x: round(x["value"], int(x["precision"])), axis=1)
Out[45]:
0    1.10
1    2.22
2    3.33
3    4.40
```

Comment: Doing this with `astype(str)` at the end will work and keep the precision level. Thank you for your suggestion. Pandas `apply` is essentially a loop. Do you know of a more efficient way to achieve the same results?

Comment: Give the precision is dynamic, I'm not aware of better method. For static precision, we have `df.round` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html